# Inverse Function in Mathematica

Tags: inverse

How to find bConst in the following code

```
For[QdB = -10, QdB <= 15, QdB++;
QConst = 10^(QdB/10);
Solve[1 - (bConst - 2/QConst )*Beta[1, 2]*
 Hypergeometric2F1[2, 1, 3, 1 - bConst] == 0.8, bConst];
Print[bConst]
]
```

I need to find bConst that makes the above expression equivalent to 0.8. I used Solve function, but it didn't work!!

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the answer you are looking for *Mathematica* to produce?  You can try `FunctionExpand` on the left hand side.

Comment: @QuantumDot Actually, the function is inside a for loop, where the left hand side is multiplied by the variable of the for loop. This implies that x must change with each loop. What I get is that x is a constant over all the loops!! This doesn't make sense.

Comment: @QuantumDot How will  FunctionExpand help finding the value of x?

Comment: Please include your *Mathematica* code.  In this case a minimal non-working example will do.

Comment: ...and with the non-working example, give the result you want/expect (explicitly).

Comment: Probably you need to use `FindRoot`, since this equation is transcendental.

Comment: @JimBaldwin I edited the original post

Comment: @march How can I use FindRoot to find bConst in my code?

Answer (score 2):

`FindRoot` with a good starting value does the job.

```
For[
  QdB = -10, 
  QdB <= 15, 
  QdB++;  
  QConst = 10^(QdB/10);  
  bConst /.  FindRoot[
                1 - (bConst - 2/QConst)*Beta[1, 2]*
                Hypergeometric2F1[2, 1, 3, 1 - bConst] == 0.8, 
               {bConst, 2.1/QConst}] // Echo
             ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If you want to gather a list of bConst values, `Table` will work better for you.

Comment: The values make sense now, but I didn't understand what you did. Why did you write bConst/. before FindRoot? In {bConst, 2.1/QConst}, why did you choose this starting point 2.1/QConst?

Comment: The output from `FindRoot` looks like `{bConst -> 20.5017}`. So when he writes `bConst /.` before `FindRoot` it is like writing `bConst /. {bConst -> 20.5017}`. This is a rule that says replace occurrences of `bConst` with the value 20.5017. Try cutting and pasting it in a fresh notebook.

Comment: `FindRoot` is happiest when it has a reasonable starting point for the solution. Some functions have multiple minimums and `FindRoot` only finds a local minimum. The value `2.1/QConst` approximates the numerical solution and so provides a good starting point.

Comment: Thanks Jack for further explanations. @EngDavid: questions about `/.` here and about `/@` and `&` (below the other answer) can be easily answered by selecting these characters and hitting F1 (help).

Comment: Thanks all. I appreciate your help. I will look into the symbols above.

Answer (score 2):

```
QdB = Range[-10, 15];

QConst = 10^(QdB/10);

Clear[bConst];

bConst = N[bConst /.
     Solve[
       1 - (bConst - 2/#)*Beta[1, 2]*
          Hypergeometric2F1[2, 1, 3, 1 - bConst] == 8/10,
       bConst, Reals][[1]]] & /@ QConst

(*  {25.6843, 20.5017, 16.3782, 13.0965, 10.4836, 8.40259, 6.74435, \
5.42232, 4.36775, 3.52598, 2.8536, 2.31611, 1.88608, 1.54172, \
1.26569, 1.0442, 0.866294, 0.72324, 0.608089, 0.515304, 0.440473, \
0.380073, 0.331294, 0.291885, 0.260043, 0.234322}  *)

ListLinePlot[bConst,
 DataRange -> QdB[[{1, -1}]],
 Frame -> True, Axes -> False,
 FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 14, Bold] & /@
    {"QdB", "bConst"})]
```

[image]

```
ListLogPlot[bConst,
 Joined -> True,
 DataRange -> QdB[[{1, -1}]],
 Frame -> True, Axes -> False,
 FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 14, Bold] & /@
    {"QdB", "bConst"})]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. The values make sense. bConst should decay as QdB gets larger. But why did you write bConst/. before Solve? What does &/@ do in the code?

Comment: @EngDavid - Read the documentation for `Solve`, `Rule`, `ReplaceAll`, `Function`, and `Map`. You need to read these to understand some of the basics of Mathematica. In general, highlight unknown symbols or operators and press `F1` (Help).

Comment: OK. I will. Thanks for your help